# jQuery change innerHTML of link based on href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, innerhtml

I have the following html generated by a CMS for a tabbed element:

```
<li class="active" style="width: 233px;">
  <a href="#tabopen_tickets">Open Tickets</a>
</li>
```

I want to change the `link's` text of "Open Tickets" to other text, but I only know the link's `href`.

How can I do this with jQuery? Thanks!

Comment: Try http://www.serverfault.com (system administrators) or http://www.superuser.com for your desktop machine problem from your deleted post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('a[href="#tabopen_tickets"]').html('your new value');
```

Answer (score 3):

Try

[Attribute Equals Selector [name="value"]](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

```
$('a[href="#tabopen_tickets"]').text('Changed');
```

---

`$('a[href="#tabopen_tickets"]')` will select the `a` tag with `href` attribute `#tabopen_tickets"`

Comment: Thanks for using text(): I hate it when people are using html() to insert text.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
$('li.active a').text("new text here");
```

if you want to get it by href then use attribute equal selector:

```
$(a[href="#tabopen_tickets"]).text("new text here");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select link with jquery that contains, start or end with some text like this
**`var link = $('a[href*="#tabopen_tickets"]')`** and
then change the link text like `link.innerHTML("new text");`
Documentation can be found [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)